# Eval() in a DropDownList within a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu

How can I do `Eval()` in a `DropDownList` that are inside a `GridView`?

I tried the follow code, but still wrong:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Prioridade">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPrioridade" runat="server"
             SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Prioridade") %>'>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: What does the error that you receive

Comment: 'ddlPrioridade' has a SelectedValue thar are invalid because he doesn't exist in the list item.
Parameter Name: value

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this way

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPrioridade" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSourceID="datasource"  DataTextField="key" DataValueField="data" AutoPostBack="True" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Prioridade") %>'>
```

also have a look at this [DropDownList inside a GridView (or DataGrid)](http://webthingsconsidered.blogspot.com/2005/09/dropdownlist-inside-gridview-or.html). It might help you

Comment: But, this is a DropDownList with Priorities. This will be loaded with the GridView. With this code, will appear just the actual Priority status, and if I wanna change de Priority status, how can I do to fill my dropdownlist with more status option different than the actual status ?

Comment: Then just add the dropdown and in the GridviewRowDataBound event you can fond the dropdown which accociate with each row and fill the dropdown with data source

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving this error because the drop down list is not loaded with items and asp.net is trying to set the selected value of an empty drop down list and that's why it gives you error. So fill the drop down list first before setting it's selected value.