# How to select the item form the dropdownlist in gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have the dropdownlist in the gridview itemtemplate, i need to select the value based on the dataset, i tried to bind it as "SelectedValue='<%# Eval("code") %>', but i cant find any attribute like "SelectedValue" in HTML code.

I tried below link also it was not work out to me

[Eval() in a DropDownList within a GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850004/eval-in-a-dropdownlist-within-a-gridview)

Can any one help me in that

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand how dropdown list (select tag) in HTML works.
E.g. if you want to select some item you have to mark it as selected as follows

```
<select>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b" selected="1">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

So you have to put `selected="1"` to item you want to select. That means you can not do it easily using `Eval` method. You have to utilize server side which will  do it for you.

The example given on the page you have postetd and which you said you have tried works correctly. Check whether the HTML output contains `value` attributes at each option. The `value` can differ from what is enclosed within the option tag. If the `value` attribute is missing that is the reason why the item is not being selected. (Use firebug or any developer console to examine).

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPaymentReason" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True"
                         DataSourceID="odsPaymentReason" DataTextField="PAYMENT_REASON_DESCRIPTION" 
                         DataValueField="PAYMENT_REASON_CODE"  SelectedText='<%# Eval("PAYMENT_REASON_CODE") %>'                       
                         ondatabound="ddlPaymentReason_DataBound" >  
                                                
                     </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: Above is my code so in that code but i cant select the value. Iam binding the list item using ObjectDataSource

Comment: Dropdown list has no such property like SelectedText. There is only SelectedValue. What are you trying to achieve? I don't quite uderstand why you have PAYMENT_REASON_CODE both in DataValueField and SelectedText...